# PostgreSQL multicolumn unique not works

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique

I have a strange situation in PostgreSQL 9.4.
I have a table:

```
id      integer                 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_userpropmeta_id_seq'::regclass)
name    character varying(255)  NOT NULL
cls     character varying(4)    NOT NULL
app_id  integer                 NOT NULL
```

And a unique constraint:
UNIQUE (app_id, name)

Now I query table:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), app_id, name FROM users_userpropmeta GROUP BY app_id, name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

And get:

```
 count | app_id |          name
-------+--------+-------------------------
     2 |   6019 | Создание серии писем
     2 |   6019 | Увеличение объемов базы
(2 rows)
```

So unique doesn't work? I've gone futher:

```
SELECT * FROM users_userpropmeta WHERE app_id=6019 AND name in ('Создание серии писем', 'Увеличение объемов базы');
  id  |          name           | cls | app_id
------+-------------------------+-----+--------
 7308 | Создание серии писем    | str |   6019
 7309 | Увеличение объемов базы | str |   6019
(2 rows)
```

Only 2 rows. Some magic is going on here. Lets's find rows with a hack:

```
SELECT MAX(id), MIN(id), COUNT(*), app_id, name FROM users_userpropmeta GROUP BY app_id, name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

 max  | min  | count | app_id |          name
------+------+-------+--------+-------------------------
 7308 | 4633 |     2 |   6019 | Создание серии писем
 7309 | 4636 |     2 |   6019 | Увеличение объемов базы
(2 rows)
```

Here are found rows:

```
SELECT * FROM users_userpropmeta WHERE id IN (7308, 7309, 4633, 4636);
  id  |          name           | cls | app_id
------+-------------------------+-----+--------
 4633 | Создание серии писем    | str |   6019
 4636 | Увеличение объемов базы | str |   6019
 7308 | Создание серии писем    | str |   6019
 7309 | Увеличение объемов базы | str |   6019
(4 rows)
```

Comparing lines one by one is correct, they are equal:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, a.name, b.name, a.name = b.name FROM users_userpropmeta AS a CROSS JOIN users_userpropmeta AS b WHERE a.id IN (7308, 7309, 4633, 4636) AND b.id IN (7308, 7309, 4633, 4636);
  id  |  id  |          name           |          name           | ?column?
------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------
 4633 | 4633 | Создание серии писем    | Создание серии писем    | t
 4633 | 4636 | Создание серии писем    | Увеличение объемов базы | f
 4633 | 7308 | Создание серии писем    | Создание серии писем    | t
 4633 | 7309 | Создание серии писем    | Увеличение объемов базы | f
 4636 | 4633 | Увеличение объемов базы | Создание серии писем    | f
 4636 | 4636 | Увеличение объемов базы | Увеличение объемов базы | t
 4636 | 7308 | Увеличение объемов базы | Создание серии писем    | f
 4636 | 7309 | Увеличение объемов базы | Увеличение объемов базы | t
 7308 | 4633 | Создание серии писем    | Создание серии писем    | t
 7308 | 4636 | Создание серии писем    | Увеличение объемов базы | f
 7308 | 7308 | Создание серии писем    | Создание серии писем    | t
 7308 | 7309 | Создание серии писем    | Увеличение объемов базы | f
 7309 | 4633 | Увеличение объемов базы | Создание серии писем    | f
 7309 | 4636 | Увеличение объемов базы | Увеличение объемов базы | t
 7309 | 7308 | Увеличение объемов базы | Создание серии писем    | f
 7309 | 7309 | Увеличение объемов базы | Увеличение объемов базы | t
(16 rows)
```

Can anyone explain, why unique constraint inserted both lines without exception? Why IN operator can't find them (I've thought of some unprintable symbols?), but equality test shows, that they are equal?

P. s. Originally, I've created subscription to PostgreSQL 9.6 with pglogical to make a logical replica from postgres to another server. And it failed with error, that it can't insert duplicated rows =).

Comment: I don't think quality does not consider spaces at the end of strings.  That is, two strings are equal, even if one has spaces and the other does not.

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version? (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.4.14 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit

Comment: @GordonLinoff May be it's some index check problem, SELECT 'abc' = 'abc ' returns false as expected.

Comment: Looks like the index is corrupted. Try to [`reindex`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html)

Comment: Do you insert those rows before or after you create the unique constraint?

Comment: @jarlh This table and index existed before me =) So I'm not sure about it.

Comment: I've catched the same case in another table. I've cleaned data. Then made REINDEX. And after a while I see a problem again...

Answer (score 1):

This has to be a corrupted index.

Experiment with `enable_seqscan = off` and see if you still find the duplicates.

Likely you will have to delete the duplicate entries by `ctid` and reindex the table.